# Infinite input until a blank space

Tags: c

How can i make an "infinite" reader that reads every input until the user just press enter?
Such as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int A;
scanf("%i", &A);

/// here i'd like to insert a loop function that will repeat every time the user insert a number 



scanf("%i, &A);
printf("Number: ", A);
/// end loop
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which? : "input until blank space" (title) or "until the user just press enter" (question body)"

Comment: There is no portable solution that uses the C library only. What platform are you talking about? I.e. what is the exact compiler used, and the operating system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> make an "infinite" reader that reads every input until the user just press enter?

This may not be truly possible by usual means to read one *long* line.

**Line limits**

> An implementation shall support text files with lines containing at least 254 characters, including the terminating new-line character. The value of the macro `BUFSIZ` shall be at least 256.  C17dr § 7.21.2 9

Maybe your implementation can handle more or maybe infinite- or code is limited to 254.

**Input buffering**

`stdin` is often line buffered.  Thus *nothing* is given to `scanf()` to process until the full line is entered including the `'\n'`.  If you can use a back-space on input to remove data, this is likely the case.

---

There are ways to over-ride buffering, some standard and some implementation specific.  You will need those. I guess this is only a partial answer about OP's goal.

---

Recommend to instead read a *line* of user input with `fgets()` with a buffer of `char buffer[BUFSIZ + 1]` and then parse that.

```
char buffer[BUFSIZ+1];
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) {

  // Parse the line looking for an int
  // Best to use strtol and family, here, for simplicity, use `sscanf()`
  int A;
  int count = sscanf(buffer, "%i", &A);
  if (count == 1) {
    printf("%d\n", A);
  } else if (buffer[0] == '\n') {
    break;
  } else {
    printf("Unexpected input <%s>\n", buffer);
    break;
  }
}
```

---

`scanf("%i", &A);` lacks the ability to detect a line of just `"\n"` as `"%i"` reads and quietly consumes all leading white-space (including new-lines) until non-white-space appears.

Comment: I mean, input 3, print something, input X, print another thing. When input a blank space the code stops.

Comment: @FelipeWatanabe Still recommend read a _line_ of input into a _string_ with `fgets()`.  When the input parses correctly as numeric text, print that.  When the input is only `"\n"`, stop.  If input is something else, print error message.

Comment: I didn't learn any commands besides loop and arrays, do you know where i can get this stuff to understand better? Or mind to show how does this ideia works (show a sample code)? I'm asking the question to begin the solution of (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-rectangular-area-in-a-histogram-set-1/)

Comment: Oh, thank you. Gonna study what you've done and try. Thank you sou much.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with you level of understanding, so my recommendation read the C standard may not work for you.  Simply search the net.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need this.

```c
int input = 1;
while (input > 0)
{
   int number;
   input = scanf("%i", &number);
   // some logic.
}
```

In this case, it sets an `input` flag to 1 and loop starts. `scanf` returns to  `input` -1 if it reads nothing else count of read elements (in this example one). Loop will be executing until NaN (not a number) is entered.

Answer (score -1):

A simple approach would be to directly check each read. Use `getchar` instead of `scanf`, it doesn't require you to hit enter after every character.

```
int main()
{
    int A = 0;
    while(A != '\n') {
        A = getchar();
        // Any other logic
    }
}
```

Comment: This is getting numerical input and then comparing it to a character.

Comment: EOF is not checked! Check the return value from `scanf`

Comment: Characters can be directly compared with integers; they are basically 8-bit inytegers themselves.

Comment: Tried and failed, doesn't stop after enter.

Comment: Sorry, its `getchar()`, not scanf. Modified.